# foreach iteration in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

How could i get two records in one iteration of  foreach loop using smarty?
OR should i use  section?

Comment: What do you mean two records exactly? Can you provide a lot more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Taken directly from documentation on http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.section.php#section.property.index.next.  Please be sure to read documentation!

```
{* $rows[row.index] and $rows[row] are identical in meaning *}
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>index</th><th>id</th>
    <th>index_prev</th><th>prev_id</th>
    <th>index_next</th><th>next_id</th>
  </tr>
{section name=row loop=$rows}
  <tr>
    <td>{$smarty.section.row.index}</td><td>{$rows[row]}</td>
    <td>{$smarty.section.row.index_prev}</td><td>{$rows[row.index_prev]}</td>
    <td>{$smarty.section.row.index_next}</td><td>{$rows[row.index_next]}</td>
  </tr>
{/section}
</table>
```

The above example will output a table containing the following:

```
index  id    index_prev prev_id index_next next_id
0      1001  -1                 1          1002
1      1002  0          1001    2          1003
2      1003  1          1002    3          1004
3      1004  2          1003    4          1005
4      1005  3          1004    5
```